# Unable to get unique element in php

Tags: php, arrays

My question is a bit jumbled up.Hope I will be able to explain. I am extracting an array from database and the result is somewhat like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 5
            [subject_name] => Pakistan Studies
            [class_title] => Commerce B
            [class_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 12
            [subject_name] => Mathematics
            [class_title] => Pre-Engineering
            [class_id] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 22
            [subject_name] => Physics
            [class_title] => Pre-Medical A
            [class_id] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 16
            [subject_name] => Psychology
            [class_title] => Humanities
            [class_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 16
            [subject_name] => Psychology
            [class_title] => Humanities
            [class_id] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 15
            [subject_name] => Accounting I
            [class_title] => Commerce B
            [class_id] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 6
            [subject_name] => Computer
            [class_title] => Commerce B
            [class_id] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 6
            [subject_name] => Computer
            [class_title] => Pre-Engineering
            [class_id] => 4
        )

)
```

I want to get result in this form

```
Array(['Commerce'=>'Computer','Accounting','Pakistan Studies'],
                 ['Pre-Engineering' =>'Computer','Mathematics'],
                 ['Humanities'    => 'Psycholgy'])
```

Can ANybody please suggest what logics can be applied in PHP. Would be really grateful.
Here is the screen shot
[image]

Comment: So what code did you write to try and achieve that?

Comment: PS It is really useful if your inputs and your required outputs make sense and have the same data in them.

Comment: I was thinking of creating my own array with looping inside a loop and making own indexes. But can't figure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a simple foreach loop creating a new array in the format you want

```
foreach($array as $in){
    $new[$in['class_title']][] = $in['subject_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a reducer:

```
$result = array_reduce($yourArray, function($acc, $item){
    $acc[$item['class_title']][] = $item['subject_name'];
  });
```

Or you use a normal foreach:

```
$result = [];
foreach( $yourArray as $item ){
  $result[$item['class_title']][] = $item['subject_name'];
}
```

Both give the result:

```
[
  'Commerce' => ['Computer','Accounting','Pakistan Studies'],
  'Pre-Engineering' => ['Computer','Mathematics'],
  'Humanities' => ['Psycholgy']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

hi the result you expect should be an array of "class_title" with a value of an array of "subject_name" like this:

```php
$result = [
    'Commerce' => ['computer', 'accounting', 'Pakistan Studies'],
    'Pre-Engineering' => ['Computer', 'Mathematics'],
    'Humanities' => ['Psycholgy']
];
```

to get there you have two options, either you browse through your entire input array and create subarrays based on the "class_title".

```php
$result = [];
foreach($courses as $course) {
    $result[$course['class_title']][] = $course['subject_name'];
}
```

or you do the exact same thing but using the "array_reduce" function.

```php
$result = array_reduce($courses, function($acc, $course) {
    $acc[$course['class_title']][] = $course['subject_name'];
    return $acc;
}, []);
```